# statically placed single row tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have statically placed a single row within UIViewController inside a storyboard. I've specified 1 prototype cell within and set its value programmatically.

But at runtime I see an extra row within the tableview, is there something I can tweak within the Attribute inspector?

[image]

My attribute inspector looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this-**

```
yourTblView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: okay, trying, just in case, anything I could change in the inspector?

Comment: No need to change anything